# Опечатка в справке на странице описания привилегий

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, нет-в-transifex

На странице "[Привилегии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges?tab=milestone)" в табах "все" и "вехи" есть пункт "Проверенный участник".
В его описании пропущена буква `е` в слове "удаление".

> Расширенное редактирование, удалени и восстановление

[image: Скриншот ошибки]

Comment: И что-то не могу найти эту строку в Transifex :\

Comment: Потому и написал сюда

Comment: Забавно. 35 человек переводят, потом перевод вытаскивают и вносят дополнительные правки (еще и с ошибками)

Comment: Странно, почему минус-то на вопросе. Граммар-анархисты?

Comment: Тут ещё и «Расширен_ое», пропущена одна «н».

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На самом деле строка в Transifex есть, но она не используется (или используется не здесь). Вот она, [Tx:1456](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/40263145?q=Expanded%20editing%2C%20deletion%20and%20undeletion%20privileges)

> Expanded editing, deletion and undeletion privileges
>
> Расширенные правки, удаление и восстановление

Тут переведённая строка верна. В истории строки видим, что последнее изменение внесено *nchabanovskii, 10 months ago*.

Подозреваю, что строки для описания привилегий берутся из альтернативного источника.

Comment: То, что там есть строка без ошибок было понятно сразу. Смутило именно то, что в Transifex она без ошибки, а в справке она в другой редакции и с ошибкой.

Comment: @tutankhamun: ну вот это потому, что часть строк — не в Transifex, а в другой системе, доступной только модераторам. Например, вся справка там.

Comment: @tutankhamun: оказалось, что справка и эти строки в разных местах (и ни одно из них — не Transifex). Вот )